# java Selenium Chrome - click button

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, button, click

Good afternoon!

I want to create a Supreme Bot. I have already tried clicking the' add to basket' button, but it just doesn't work.

I need some help!

Source code from the Supreme side:

[Screenshot from the sourcecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqdOV.png)

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='add to basket']")).click();
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you specify the Xpath Path by yourself or did you use the Xpath for the object as given by chrome in the Element Inspector? A similar sample button on eBay gave me the following selector: `//input[@value="Find"]`, so maybe it's not even a button.

Comment: doens't work too

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Select the button you want to click in the Element inspector, right-click it > Copy > Copy Xpath. Then use this path in your Selenium code. If it doesn't work either, make sure you are traversing the right parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using xpath as :

```
//input[@value='add to basket']
```

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset[@id='add-remove-button']/input")))).click();

Answer (score 1):

Use JavascriptExecutor,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='add to basket']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all buttons and verify the name :

```
input_fields = webdriver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
for field in input_fields:
    if field.get_attribute('name') == 'commit'
        field.click()
```

Edit: Mistake, I wrote the answer in python but the logic still holds true for Java, just need to change the syntax.